# 3 fixed width columns, center middle one

Tags: html, css

I have 3 columns of width 225px set up like this:

```
<div id="main">
     <div id="col1">
         <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="col3">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As the borowser window reduces I want col1 to float left, col3 to float right and col2 to sit in the middle with the margin between col2 and col1/2 adjusting

I have this css - which doesn't  work!

```
#main {
    width:100%;
}

.col1,.col2,.col3 {
    width:225px;
}

.col 1, .col2 {
    float:left;
}

.col 3{
    float:right;
}

.col2 {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: try set `width` for .col3, and `display:inline-block` for 3 cols

Comment: A couple of your selectors have spaces in: `.col 1` and `.col 3`.

Comment: oh boy - sorry about the code... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/NXRzP/

First, i added a div inside the div.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="col1">...</div>
    </div>
...
```

On the CSS there are a few things to notice:

- There where a few errors in your original CSS, with spaces in the class names, and wrong selector (Use "#" for id, and "." for class)
- The outer Div have a width of 33%, so it distributes to the whole page.
- The inner Div are floated left/right and center with margin auto.
- Added a minimum width to the "main" div, so the columns don't overlap when it's too narrow.

Here's the complete CSS:

```
.main {
  width:100%;
  min-width: 700px;
}

.col {
  width:33%;
  float:left; 
}

.col1, .col2, .col3 { 
  width:225px; 
  background-color: #999 
}

.col1  { float:left; }
.col2  { margin: 0 auto; }
.col3  { float: right }
```

Comment: thanks for this answer Ariel - does exactly what I want - interesting little fix!

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces in your class name like `.col 1`:

```
.col1, .col2 {
float:left;
}

.col3{
float:right;
}
```

and your html has ID's instead classes.

Answer (score 0):

You use class selector instead of id selector `#`. I create an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/P9Rz6/show/) where you can do not set `#col2` width, but you need to change html:

```
<div id="main">
     <div id="col1">
         <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="col3">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#col1, #col3 {
    width:225px;
}

#col1  {
    float:left;
}

#col3{
    float:right;
}

#col2 {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all div id to class . You coded all col div as id  http://jsfiddle.net/Szp68/2/

```
 <div id="main">
<div class="col1">
<p>...</p>
</div>
<div class="col2">
<p>...</p>
</div>
<div class="col3">
<p>...</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too much errors in your code. You use `class` indeed `id` in your css..

Try this code : <kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ExTG/7/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="col1">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="col3">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (you can remove colors, there are here just for the example)

```
#main {
    width:100%;
    background : red;
}

#col1, #col2, #col3 {
    width:33%; // or 225px
    float:left;
}

#col1{
    background:green;
}

#col2{
    background:blue;
}

#col3{
    background:purple;
}
```

Comment: Just the margin is missing between two columns?